# Reload Methods: Complete Ajax Solutions

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

My web application utilizes page reloads in places where the page structure changes.

For content changes initiated by the user it is all handled by Ajax.

However I'm planning on removing all the page reloads and replacing them with ajax calls that simply update the page using innerHTML for the body and head tags.

To do this I know have to manually call functions that are normally called by the onload event.

When I am done I will have a complete ajax application. My question is, is this standard practice now....I see a lot of applications where you do something and the whole page reloads, where even common elements are reloaded.

For example go to Apple.com and hit on the first button you see "Store"...you will see the whole page reload even the menu bar that does not change is reloaded wasting bandwidth..

Because I don't see other people using complete ajax solutions...I wonder if I am headed down a wrong path.

My question?

Is a complete ajax based web application best practice? (of course file uploads aren't supported, omitting this, is it best practice).

If so why do big sites not do it?  I see few sites that actually employ ajax instead of page reloads.

Comment: One of the biggest disadvantages to doing everything in ajax is losing out in search engines. Search engines crawl your page looking for links they can follow to other pages on site. If you are doing everything in ajax, you won't have any links, and the search engine will probably see your site as just one page, significantly reducing the chances that your site will show up in a search.

Comment: this does not change any of the links..I would still need the static versions available in case the user hits the reload button...there would be both the static pages..and ajax generated pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons **not** to go fully ajax. A few are:

1. If the user refreshes the page they'd be sent back to the home page;
   if they pressed the back button, they'd go back to the previous site
   they visited.
2. Search engines won't be able to index anything past the home page.
3. Anyone without javascript enabled or on IE 6 (or it's equivalent) wouldn't be able to use the site.

Lastly, it can be hell to debug a problem -- I went full ajax on a project a while ago and ended up regretting it.

If none of the above are important to your project, and you're looking to do something different, then by all means -- the real question you need to ask is "does the added complexity justify the savings in bandwidth?".

Comment: 1.  No I have a Session variable tracking the page they are on...so there is a static page as well for when they hit reload.

Comment: 1. cont...if they press back that is what I want to happen.

Comment: 3.  Modern apps require javascript

Comment: How does search indexing work..there has to be a way around this..for example facebook has a billion users but they don't link off of their main page..I'm sure I can get what I need in the search engine

Comment: Yes, b.c. the web has always found a way to be slow...developers seem to pretend this isn't a fact of life..but it is.

Comment: 2. Hmm, I still feel that user's would be annoyed by this -- almost all of the web uses the back button to go to the previous page, if it suddenly took me back to the previous site it would throw me off. That's just personal preference though..

Comment: 3. *most* modern apps require javascript but I have a few paranoid friends who browse without it. Still, if the links in the site still use actual url's and you use javascript to overwrite their default behaviour then this shouldn't be a problem. Same with indexing issues.

Comment: 4. There is: Search engines use the source code of the page when it first loads. They don't run javascript or anything that modifies the page after it has loaded. If you keep your links pointing to the actual page and use jquery or javascript to over write their default behaviour and load content via ajax rather than changing the user's location, then the search engine should still be able to crawl through your site.

Comment: 5. You do have a point, and I think that for mobi sites it's important to keep load times to an absolute minimum, but overall I think that going fully ajax adds too much complexity for too little reward (i.e. additional dev hours, complexity etc.) esp when bigger sites are invloved.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of ajax is reload certain content of the page when you don't need to change all the content.

Your example of apple.com: it isn't a best practice to use ajax in navigation, because the history of browser don't handle this (use the back button of the browser and the navigation will not respond if you use ajax, keep that in mind).

If you have a box with testimonials and want them to change from time to time, so it's a good place to use ajax, avoiding the whole page to reload.

You can also have a static page with all testimonials to let search mecanisms to index that content.

Example of big sites? The search of google. When you type only the box of results is reloaded to view one preview.

So you have to choose when use and when not use ajax.

Comment: no..why would you hit back when you could just hit the button you need..it does not matter.

Comment: If it was ajax instead of hitting back you would just hit the menu button...this makes more sense in my mind..it might just be a matter of preference

Comment: @stack.user.0 unfortunately not all users think equals you and one of them can hit the back button and you don't have the possibility of disable this browser feature.

Comment: I see your point but my site is simple and small..there is no reason a user would want to "back up" in my site...but I can kind of see why sites like google.com and apple.com....do reloads...so that you can back up...I still disagree...I think the site should be seen as an application..and hitting back should take your to the previous application or domain...

Comment: Inter application navigation should be handled by the applicaion..I think users can figure this out....but yea you are correct this is not common practice..

Comment: @stack.user.0 Also, if your site is small you don't need to spend time making he more complex. Search mecanisms will se this as one site and not an application and the full ajax will not be indexed by them.

Comment: I will have static pages for when the user hits reload and these will be indexed.